# How use properly THIS in javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm using the Object.init pattern in my application. Where within the init i initialize variables attached to the object, for example:

```
var MyObject = {

 init: function() {
   this.element = $('.someElement');


   this.element.bind('click', this._doSomething.bind(this));
 },

 _doSomething = function() {
    // METHOD WHICH I WILL MANIPULATE THIS.ELEMENT

 }

};
```

What i'm trying to know is, if i have to create some variables inside the method _doSomething, should i attach the variables to the MyObject with this, like this:

```
this.someVar = 'something';
```

Or should i use var:

```
var someVar = 'something';
```

I think the best way is use this if i will use the someVar in other parts of MyObject, and i should var if i use only in the scope of _doSomething method.

But this is my opinion, i want know the best practice.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, would you have your variable to be accesible or not? Attaching a property to the object makes it "public".

Comment: Use a closure (to capture the "current context" or element); use `Function.bind`; or use the additional event data with the jQuery handler.

Comment: `"I think the best way is use this if i will use the someVar in other parts of MyObject, and i should var if i use only in the scope of _doSomething method."` - That sounds about right!

Comment: `this.element.bind('click', this._doSomething.bind(this))`

Answer (score -1):

Your presumption is correct; use `this.myVar` for anything with a lifetime longer than one function.

To give you a better idea of how this works, your object can associate a string key like "myVar" with a variable. `this.myVar` is shorthand for `this["myVar"]`. Might look a little weird, but that's standard for setting/retrieving JS properties.

However, `var myVar` declarations are not associated with any one object; they survive for the lifetime of the function. They can be preserved if you have a function inside of a function, but that's not what you were asking about. If you are curious though, look up the term "closures".

Comment: So it is correct to say that using 'var' the performance will be better?

Comment: @Amanda Ferrari, not really... it will provide some sort of encapsulation.

Comment: This will not solve the OPs problem - which is that `this` in the jQuery callback will not be that of the object. Also, the OP already has `this.element` ..

Comment: but if the lifetime is shorter using var, this means that the garbage collector will throw it away, no?

Comment: It will be left for the GC to pick it up yes, however by doing assignments every time you call the function you are also wasting some resources.

Comment: Hm interesting @MinusFour.. so, thinking about performance, what is the best choice here if i'm going to call just one time?

Comment: @user2864740 Maybe you saw an earlier edit than me, but I don't see anything wrong; `this` will have the same reference during either function. @Amanda - If you're beginning with JavaScript, don't concern yourself too too much with performance. `var`s will be local and temporary, making sense for certain things if you only need them a short time.

Comment: @Katana314 It will *not* 'have the same `this` object' - because the method (used as a generic callback) is invoked via *jQuery's* event binding (`$.bind` is not to be confused with `Function.prototype.bind`).

Comment: @Katana314 The `this` in the callback should be the DOM element itself that is the even target (but not the object with the `element` property; and not the jQuery object).

Comment: @user2864740 First, JQuery will invoke its `$().bind` handler. This will have the DOM element as the `this` element. However, the handling function it then calls is the correct `Function.prototype.bind`-bound function, so it will call that method with the MyObject`this` context. IF the line were written as `this.element.bind('click', this._doSomething);`, then you would be correct.

Answer (score -1):

The fact you named your function _doSomething, tells me it's a candidate for an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript). It's not accessible to the outside and you can interface with your object using foo.init();

Edit: changed listener, as per comment

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mqs170mh/1/)

```
var foo = (function(){

    // private function
    function doSomething() {
    // METHOD WHICH I WILL MANIPULATE THIS.ELEMENT
        alert('doSomething()');
    }

    var myObject = {
        init: function() {
            this.message = 'hello init';
            this.element = $('.someElement');
            this.element.on('click', function() { doSomething.call(this); }.bind(this));
            alert(this.message);
        }
    };

    return myObject;

})();

foo.init();
```

Comment: Using `Function.call` will result in `doSomething` being called right away and is equivalent to writing `this.element.bind('click', doSomething(this))`.

Comment: The extra function is not needed and looks like it muddling up use of a (non used) closure. Just use `this.element.on('click', doSomething.bind(this));`